# Why is my Vertical Bootstrap Navbar breaking my page?

Tags: html, css, navbar

Basically, my bootstrap vertical navbar has a margin that stretches from its right side, all the way to the right side of the page.

[image]

This is what my Vertical Navbar looks like, with only it on the page, without any other content.
However, when I add another element on the page, it pushes it down, as shown in the image below, the black box is being pushed down. Highlighted in red is the margin being created by the navbar.
[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
family=Montserrat:wght@100;200;300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2d7a97658d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <div class = "section-1">
                <div class = "nav-title"><i class="fas fa-user icon"></i>User</div>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Settings <i class="fas fa-angle-right 
                    arrow"></i></a>
                </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Notifications</a>
               </li>  
            </div>
      
      <div class = "nav-title"><i class="fas fa-wallet icon"></i>Billing</div>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          
      </ul>

   
   <div class = "info-box">
       
       Hello
       
       
       
       
       
   </div>


 <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
    DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
   </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
     integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>

.flex-column, .nav {width: 25%;
background-color: #f4f4f8;
height: 100vh;
margin-right: 0 !important;}

.nav-title {display: block;
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';}

a {text-decoration: none !important;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
list-style: none;}

.nav-link {padding-left: 2em !important;
           font-size: 1.1em ;
            transition:color 0.2s, background-color 0.4s, padding 0.4s;
            
            }


.nav-link:link {padding-left: 1em !important;
           font-size: 1.1em;
            }


.nav-link:hover {
    padding-left: 1.5em !important;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background-color: #f0f0f4;
    
            }


.nav-link {padding-left: 1em !important;
           font-size: 1.1em ;
            transition:color 0.2s, background-color 0.4s, padding 0.4s;
            
            
            }


.nav-link:link {padding-left: 1em !important;
           font-size: 1.1em;
            
            }


.nav-link:hover {
    padding-left: 1.5em !important;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background-color: #f0f0f4;
    color: #009dff !important;
    
            }

.active {
    padding-left: 1.5em !important;
    font-size: 1.1em!important;
    background-color: #f0f0f4!important;
    color: #009dff!important;}

.active:link {
    padding-left: 1.5em !important;
    font-size: 1.1em!important;
    background-color: #f0f0f4!important;
    color: #009dff!important;}

.active;hover {
    padding-left: 1.5em !important;
    font-size: 1.1em!important;
    background-color: #f0f0f4!important;
    color: #009dff!important;}

.arrow {
margin-left:65%;
display: flex;
margin-top: none !important;}

.icon {margin: auto 0.1em;}

.info-box {width: 5em;
height: 10em;
margin-top: 0.2em;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background-color: black;
display: block;}
```

https://codepen.io/smallbluecactus/pen/YzqbQjX

Be sure to put this into ur code editor, because it looks different on codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a container around the ul to tell the area spacing to become aligned. Right now your ul nav is flexboxed just by itself. Anything you try to put next to it will just go below as you need to group the nav with whatever you want to put next to it. If you inspect there's technically no margin with the nav although it looks like it.

```html
    <div class="d-flex">
        <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <div class = "section-1">
                <div class = "nav-title"><i class="fas fa-user icon"></i>User</div>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Settings <i class="fas fa-angle-right arrow"></i></a>
                </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Notifications</a>
               </li>  
            </div>
      
      <div class = "nav-title"><i class="fas fa-wallet icon"></i>Billing</div>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          
      </ul>

   
   <div class = "info-box">
       Hello
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Portman, it worked. Also, why did you downvote? lmao

Comment: You're Welcome. And I didn't must've been someone else.

Comment: Mind upvoting mine and label it as the answer?